# How to add dynamically created table at perticular location

Tags: asp.net

In my web form,from cs file I am creating dynamic table.After clicking on that button ,table get created.But it go to above content page.

```
protected void button_click()
{         
    string s1 = "Computer"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>"); 
    sb.Append("document.write('<table><tbody>')";); 
   sb.Append("document.write('<tr><td>Information</td></tr>')";); 
    if(s1 == "Computer" ) 
   {
     sb.Append("<tr><td>"+s1+"</td></tr>"); 
   }
   sb.Append("document.write('</tbody></table>')";);
   sb.Append(@"</script>"); 



 if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup"))

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup", sb.ToString());  
    }
```

I have created table like this.

Comment: why don't you try to do it on client side using jquery?

Comment: Because I wanted to pass value some variable of cs file to that table like S1.

Answer (score 0):

You need return Content.

example:

```
    public ContentResult DynamicallyTable()
    { 
   string s1 = "Computer"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // please set size
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>"); 
    sb.Append("document.write('<table><tbody>')";); 
   sb.Append("document.write('<tr><td>Information</td></tr>')";); 
    if(s1 == "Computer" ) 
   {
     sb.Append("<tr><td>"+s1+"</td></tr>"); 
   }
   sb.Append("document.write('</tbody></table>')";);
   sb.Append(@"</script>"); 
    return new Content(){Content = sb.ToString()};
    }
```